# Where is the "unattended-upgrades" email notification template?

Tags: 16.04, server, unattended-upgrades

I'm using Ubuntu Server (16.04) with "unattended-upgrades", and I've set everything in order to receive notification emails when this packages does its thing. Now I want to change the notification content for edit the text so I can add some data to it or make some text bold (examples given).

Where can I find the notification "template"?

Comment: add a alias  in your mailrc file ref: https://askubuntu.com/a/554775/783050

Comment: @An0n Is clearly not a duplicated. I even tried to make the title different because that other post has the title that I should use. I'm talking about the notification email content. Thanks for that other link tho!

Comment: I know its not.. Thats why i posted the other link. Im not good at finding duplicates and also hate it to compare questions. This was the last time i flag a duplicate tho ;) Anyway is your issue fixed ?

Comment: My issue seems unable to be fixed, from what @muru says in his reply :(

Answer (score 4):

It's in the code. The mail body is generated programatically in Python. Look for the function [`send_summary_mail`](https://sources.debian.org/src/unattended-upgrades/1.0/unattended-upgrade/#L956) in `/usr/bin/unattended-upgrade`. As a result, it's not easy to change the mail content, since any edits to `/usr/bin/unattended-upgrade` will be lost when the `unattended-upgrades` package is updated.

Comment: Well, damn it! Thanks for the information.

Comment: I you have a good proposal, you can contribute to the [source code](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades) and get your changes permanent.