# smtp send email on unattended upgrades in Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, email, sendmail

Hello I have setup unattended upgrades on my Ubuntu 20.04 server with msmtp and sendmail.
And want to send the result of Unattended-Upgrade to my email. But the email is not sending by Unattended-Upgrade!

I have add my email Adress to the Unattended-Upgrade settings:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "me@yahoo.de";
```

My `/etc/mail.rc` looks like:

```
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp -t"
```

My msmtp config (`/etc/msmtprc`) looks like:

```
defaults
port 587
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

account me@yahoo.de
host smtp.mail.yahoo.com
from me@yahoo.de
auth on
logfile /var/log/msmtp
user me@yahoo.de
password abc
account default: me@yahoo.de
aliases /etc/aliases
```

With the permissions:

```
ls -l /etc/msmtprc    
-rw-r----- 1 root msmtp 2741 Dec 15 12:23 /etc/msmtprc
```

The same config I have in my user Dir (`/home/me/.msmtprc`):

```
ls -l /home/me/.msmtprc                                       
-rw------- 1 me msmtp 2725 Dec 15 09:51 /home/me/.msmtprc
```

Now I'm able to successfully send emails with:

```
echo "content" | mail -s "test email" me@yahoo.de
```

the log of the command above in /var/log/msmtp is:

```
Dec 15 13:04:31 host=smtp.mail.yahoo.com tls=on auth=on user=me@yahoo.de from=me@yahoo.de recipients=me@yahoo.de mailsize=153 smtpstatus=250 smtpmsg='250 OK , completed' exitcode=EX_OK
```

But when I run unattended-upgrade manually `sudo /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade -d` I get:

```
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
Sending mail to me@yahoo.de
sendmail: the server sent an empty reply
sendmail: could not send mail (account default from /etc/msmtprc)
mail returned: 76
```

The log of the cammand above is:

```
Dec 15 13:23:03 host=smtp.mail.yahoo.com tls=on auth=on user=me@yahoo.de from=me@yahoo.de recipients=me@yahoo.de errormsg='the server sent an empty reply' exitcode=EX_PROTOCOL
```

Comment: I was having a very similar issue. [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233655) worked for me.